# Default project id in BigQuery Java API

Tags: google-bigquery

I am performing a query using the BigQuery Java API with the following code:

```
  try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(serviceAccountKeyFile)) {

     GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(input);

     BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
           .setCredentials(credentials)
           .build()
           .getService();

     QueryRequest request = QueryRequest.of("SELECT * FROM foo.Bar");
     QueryResponse response = bigQuery.query(request);

     // Handle the response ...

  }
```

Notice that I am using a specific service account whose key file is given by `serviceAccountKeyFile`.

I was expecting that the API would pick up the `project_id` from the key file.  But it is actually picking up the `project_id` from the default key file referenced by the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

This seems like a bug to me.  Is there a way to workaround the bug by setting the default project explicitly?

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, that doesn't sound right at all. It does sound like a bug. I always just use the export the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable in our applications.

Anyway, you try explicitly setting the project id to see if it works:

```
BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .setProjectId("project-id") //<--try setting it here
                    .build()
                    .getService();
```

Comment: .setProjectId("project-id") did the trick for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the project is coming from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I suspect that the project being picked up is the gcloud default project set by `gcloud init` or `gcloud config set project`.

From my testing, BigQuery doesn't use a project where the service account is created. I think the key is used only for authorization, and you always have to set a target project. There are a number of ways:

1. `.setProjectId(<target-project>)` in the builder
2. Define `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`
3. `gcloud config set project <target-project>`

The query job will then be created in `target-project`. Of course, your service key should have access to `target-project`, which may or may not be the same project where your key is created. That is, you can run a query on projects other than the project where your key is created, as long as your key has permission to do so.